# Not able to get groups that belong to current user

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm building a Django app that needs two things. First, it needs the set of groups that the user has access to. With this set of groups, my template is supposed to create a button for each group. Next, it needs the set of "Property" objects that are ManyToMany related to a group in the previously found set of groups (this is to say that I need every property that is assigned to a group that the user has access to). For each of these properties, a button is created. I'm working with an admin user on localhost right now while building this, and I've created a test group with test properties and assigned the admin user to that group. Django however, doesn't seem to be detecting this. The relevant code is below:

views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.shortcuts import render
from UsageData.models import Property, User, Group, MeterData
from django.contrib import auth    

def reports_proerty_list(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated():

        current_user_groups = Group.objects.filter(id__in=request.user.groups.all())
        current_user_properties = Property.objects.filter(groups__in=current_user_groups)

        return render(request, 'App/App-Template-Page.html')

    else:

        # The user is redirected to the sign-in page
```

App-Template-Page.html

```
        <div class="row">

        {% if current_user_groups %}
            {% for group in current_user_groups %}
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">{{ group.name }}</button>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">Group 1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">Group 2</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">Group 3</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">Group 4</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">Group 5</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-center">
                <button class="tab-selector inactive" id="{{ group.id }}">Group 6</button>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the {% else %} part of the template displays when the page loads, which I suppose means that current_user_groups doesn't exist. Anyone know why this might be happening? I naturally can't proceed with what I want to do with the Property objects without this working first. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't pass any of your variables into context of a [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function

```
  return render(request, 'App/App-Template-Page.html',{
    'current_user_groups': current_user_groups,
    'current_user_properties': current_user_properties 
})
```

Also this line could be simplified

```
current_user_groups = Group.objects.filter(id__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

to

```
current_user_groups = request.user.groups.all()
```

Comment: Wow I'm silly for not remembering to do this. Thank you so much! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Comment: No problem things like this can happen :)